# Where do I find the sketches for part #1 and part #2?

Tags: great-adventures-lim

It seems I'm almost at the end in Great Adventures: Lost in Mountains.

I've already obtained all the parts required for the goal to make part #1 and part #2 except for the sketches.

Where do I find the sketches for part #1 and part #2, and how do I get them?

Comment: Created a tag for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this walkthrough](http://www.gamezebo.com/games/great-adventures-lost-mountains/walkthrough), you'll need to go to Suite #4 to get the mirror, and then use the mirror in Suite #1 on the lasers.  This opens up the rest of the suite, where you'll find sketch parts #1 and #2.

(If you need more help, and you'd rather not be spoiled by consulting the walkthrough, edit your question and post a comment on my answer and I'll try to add more specific detail.)